# SQL INNER JOIN LIMIT RESULTS WHERE ID UNIQUE And Date most RECENT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm new to SQL and working on a select statement which should return a table result as documented below. The goal is to return a table with one row for each ThreadID that exists and has a CatID that matches the CatID being queried, then filter the result/limit the result so that only the most recent post is returned and to return the ordered results based on date created:

Date Created dates revised to make it more apparent which date i want form each possible row returned (Most RecentDate where CatID=1) If the data existed in one table i could write this I think, but this is apparently beyond my understanding.

```
╔══════════╔══════════╦═══════════════╦════════╦═════════════╗ 
║  CatID   ║ ThreadID ║  ThreadTitle  ║ PostID ║ DateCreated ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬═══════════════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║    4     ║     7    ║    Title A    ║   12   ║ most recent ║
║    4     ║     6    ║    Title B    ║   6    ║ most recent ║
║    4     ║     12   ║    Title C    ║   45   ║ most recent ║
║    4     ║     3    ║    Title D    ║   2    ║ most recent ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩═══════════════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

I have been reading through PHPfreaks, W3schools, obviously StackOverflow and attempting to model my results using Adminer. I've learned a bit about joins which i've not attempted to do before, but after several hours of trying (6 hours) i feel comfortable asking for help.

My attempts have either produce nothing found, 1 result, or 8000+ results. I should have 4 results with my actual test data.

This is my latest attempted sql, which is not working as hoped

```
SELECT
    mat.ThreadTitle,
    mat.CatID,

    map.DateCreated AS "RecentID",
    map.ThreadID,
    map.LastUpdated


    FROM
            ma_Threads AS mat
    INNER JOIN
            ma_Posts AS map

    ON mat.CatID = '$catID' 

WHERE       `pat.DateCreated(test.marvelchampions)` = (
 SELECT MAX(DATE(pat.DateCreated))
 FROM `pat`
```

)

Comment: Could you please provide ddl for tables? Are there any common columns that you should use in join?

Comment: strtolower($thread->title);

Comment: We need to see the definition of tables ma_Threads and ma_Posts to debug SQL.  Please add to question.

Comment: `ma_Threads AS mat INNER JOIN ma_Posts AS map ON mat.CatID = '$catID'` should have something else there like `AND mat.CatID=map.CatID` (or whatever column they have in common).  You have to tell it how the two tables relate to each other.  Otherwise you will get far more records than you expect.

Comment: You have to show us the columns that are in each table. Then it should be easy

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

The following should work, assuming my guess regarding the definition of tables is correct

```
SELECT
  ma_Threads.CatID,
  ma_Threads.ID AS ThreadID,
  ma_Threads.ThreadTitle,
  ma_Posts.ID AS PostID,
  ma_Posts.LastUpdated

FROM ma_Threads
JOIN ma_Posts ON (
    ma_Posts.ID = (
        SELECT MAX(ma_Posts2.ID)
        FROM ma_Posts ma_Posts2
        WHERE ma_Posts2.ThreadID = ma_Threads.ID
    )
)
WHERE ma_Threads.CatID = '$catID'
ORDER BY ma_Posts.LastUpdated DESC
```

Comment: It isn't working :( LastCreated should be DateAdded. The data is coming form two tables, both tables have ThreadID, PostID, CatID, I need to get the Title

Comment: Sorry to add a comment - i was editing and got hit with the five minute limit which i didn't know existed. ---The error reads as follows 'Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'WHERE ma_Threads.CatID = '1' ORDER BY ma_Posts.DateCreated DESC' at line 16'  -- i tried running it without the DESC, still got the error. I changed LastCreated should be DateCreated when i ran as that is the table i want referenced.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. I received this error: Error in query (1054): Unknown column 'ma_Threads.ID' in 'field list'. I tried to revise it changing ma_Threads.ThreadID but this did not work for me

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your tables. But my best guess would be:

```
SELECT mat.ThreadTitle,
       mat.CatID,
       map.DateCreated AS "RecentID",
       map.ThreadID,
       MAX(map.LastUpdated)
FROM ma_Threads AS mat
INNER JOIN ma_Posts AS map
ON mat.CatID = map.CatID
GROUP BY mat.ThreadTitle, mat.CatID, map.DateCreated, map.ThreadID
```